# Trying to set the cookie

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the cookie value using:

```
 function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value, lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
 {
  var domain_string = valid_domain ? ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
  document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +"; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * lifespan_in_days +"; path=/" + domain_string ;
  }
```

...trying to use them in the `onclick` function below:

```
 function dataReview_tasks(inputObj)
  {
   var info = new IOInfo(inputObj);
   var id = info.key(0);
   setcookie(<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>,id,1,"");
   var redirect_page = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DataReviewNEW.aspx") %>';
    window.location = redirect_page;
    }
```

But getting error in `setcookie()` is *undefined*. Can you please help me with this, am I doing this the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Your function is called `set_cookie`, but you're calling `setcookie`.

Change:

```
setcookie(<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>,id,1,"");
```

To:

```
set_cookie(<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>,id,1,"");
```